# Withdraw money feature for paypal

Tags: paypal

Basically I have a script where user should have Withdraw button on his account so he can automatically withdraw money from my paypal balance

What API should I use in this case and is this available at all for paypal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be interested in the Mass Pay API.  You can send them in batches, say daily, weekly, or monthly.

See here for an explination directly from paypal:
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_masspay

> The MassPay API allows you to send payments to up to 250 recipients with a single API call. The payment amount for each recipient is specified individually, but all payments in a MassPay API request must have the same currency type. You can choose to specify recipients by email address or PayPal customer account number.

And here for PHP examples (if you're using PHP):
https://www.x.com/paypal-apis-masspay-php-5.3/soap

There are additional examples and a large amount of documentation on the first PayPal.com link, regardless of programming language used.

Please keep in mind Mass Pay has it's own fee schedule.

There is also Adaptive payments, which may be more up your alley, as it's designed for more fine-grained control and has a larger API available.  Information can be obtained here:

https://www.x.com/content/introducing-adaptive-payments

**However, the Adaptive payments will require approval of each Payment by you (the sender) via the PayPal website.  If you want 100% automation, the Mass Pay API is the way to go.**

Please realize a mistake here could cost you infinate amounts of money, so tread **extremely carefully.**

Answer (score 2):

If you're attempting to withdraw money from your PayPal account and move it to your bank account that's not something you can do via the API, unfortunately.  You have to do that manually through PayPal, or you can call them and request that they enable AutoSweep for you, which will automatically move the balance in PayPal to your bank at the end of each day.

Comment: Damn, I guess I'll have to scrape their site to automate this :/

Answer (score 2):

Ya there is preapproval api in AdaptivePayment. You can approve the api caller for the  amount he want to withdraw from your account on your behalf.

You can refer api here : https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/preapproval-api-operation

Comment: you mean, a user can withdraw funds from paypal to bank account using API?